# How to call custom method after dynamic control added to the form in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am working in Angular 4 with SharePoint. I would like to call one method after creating dynamic controls to the form. Could you please provide the solution for the same? I used the below code to generate dynamic control while pressing the "+" icon in my form.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of actionPlans; let i = index">
<div class="row"><div class="form-group"><label>Action Plan</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="actionPlan-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.actionPlan">
</div></div></div>
```

Typescript code as follows:-

`private actionPlans: any = [];private addActionPlan() { this.actionPlans.push({}); }`

I want to call the below method after the dynamic item is added to the screen. In the below method I want to access the control Id and some operations. Could you please any one help me on this?

`private getActionPlan() { // do some actvities }`

Regards,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

I guess your "control" is actually an action plan ?

If you need to call a custom method once you press the **+** button, then you need to add an eventHandler to your button with a simple

```
(click)="doSomething()"
```

But you probably already did that, so if you want to call your method hen you have added the control, you must do

```
doSomething() {
  // Your code to add a control
  this.myCustomMethod();
}
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Hi, I already call the custom method (addActionPlan() {....}) to generate the dynamic control. But I want to call another method after the control is added to the form. I want to access the control id from the dynamic form. Thanks.

Comment: Your queston is very unclear. If you want to call a custom method after you added a control, then just call it at the end of your function that adds the control ! Otherwise you will have to be more explicit and mind your wording, because I really can't get what you want.

Comment: Hi, Detail explanation is here. Initially I declare the variable metricActionPlans as empty array. This variable is referred in *ngFor loop in html file. In ngOnInit() method I add the code as this.metricActionPlans.push({}) to generate the initial control in the form. When I add "+" icon in my form, I called "addActionPlan()" method and in this method I again use the same code "this.metricActionPlans.push({})" to add new row. At this time the control is added to the screen. Now I want to access the name of control id after it added to the form. How can I do that?

Comment: Well both of your cases seem obvious ... You want to call `getActionPlan` after you added a control ? here is your code : `addActionPlan() { this.actionPlans.push({}); this.getActionPlan(); }`. You want to get the id of the added control ? Here is your code : `addActionPlan() { this.actionPlans.push({}); let lastControlName = 'actionPlan-' + (this.actionPlans.length - 1); }`. I'm sorry, but this seems so obvious, I think I am not understanding your question.

Comment: As per your code, actionPlans length is increased by one when I click on the "+" icon, but at that time, the control name is not reflected in DOM. I searched the control name (ex. actionPlan-1) in "Elements" tab in Chrome but it is not appear. But "actionPlan-0" is appear. I think you understand now. Thanks again for your patient. The above scenarios which I tested in debug mode.

Comment: My code will work, since you don't rely on the DOM to get the name, you only create a string matching the control name. Go ahead, try it, you will see ! I am starting to get it, but I don't see why you would get the name of a created element like that. Usually, you should give your purpose too, so that wen can offer you a better way of doing what you want.

Comment: I want to add the SharePoint people picker control in dynamic form when ever "+" icon is clicked. I've created separate component to handle the people picker. Now I want to send the unique id to the people picker method to render the control when ever I clicked "+" icon. As of now I passed the unique id but the DOM is not available so the control is not rendered.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) that are way easier to use (for your case). They will allow you to create sub forms so that you don't have to struggle like a madman (reactiveForms have values even when the DOM isn't rendered yet) and do whatever you can to retrieve your data !

Comment: Thanks for provide the solution. I'll try this approach. Thanks again.